# Fibonacci sequence program in python working fine except for input 0

Tags: python, fibonacci

This program is showing correct output except for input n=0.

```
def fib(n):
    f=list()
    i=0
    while(i<=n):
        f.append(i)
        i+=1
    f[0]=0
    f[1]=1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        f[i]=f[i-1]+f[i-2]
        i+=1
    return f[n]
n=int(input())
print(fib(n))
```

when i give input n=0, it shows the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "fib.py", line 16, in <module>
        print(fib(n))
    File "fib.py", line 10, in fib
        f[1]=1
    IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: When n=0 you don't have a value in position 1 of f but your sentence is trying to read te value in that position _f[1]=1_. Probably you got confused with dictionaries.
BTW, try to follow PEP8 in your Python code.

Answer (score 1):

Two lines in the middle are not necessary due to you initializing those elements during while loop. And error comes from the fact, that for `n=0`, you were only adding one elemnt to list. And after that changing value of first and second element. There is no second element.

```
def fib(n):
    f=[]
    i=0
    while(i<=n):
        f.append(i)
        i+=1
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        f[i]=f[i-1]+f[i-2]
        i+=1
    return f[n]
n=int(input())
print(fib(n))
```

Comment: @Destrif Not at all! Why would you think so? (tested this as well)

Answer (score 0):

Either duck type it:

```
def fib(n):
    if n in [0, 1]:
        return n
    .
    .
```

Or change `f[0] = 0` and `f[1] = 1` to `f.append(0)` and `f.append(1)` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this two lines.

```
f[0]=0
f[1]=1
```

Remove them and everything will work.

Answer (score 0):

Corrections to your code:

```
def fib(n):
    f=list()
    i=0
    while(i<=n):
        f.append(i)
        i+=1
    # HERE WAS THE MISTAKE
    f.append(0)
    f.append(1)
    for i in range(2,n+1):
        f[i]=f[i-1]+f[i-2]
        i+=1
    return f[n]
```

Outputs:

```
>>> fib(0)
0
>>> fib(1)
1
>>> fib(2)
1
>>> fib(3)
2
>>> fib(4)
3
>>> fib(5)
5
>>> fib(6)
8
>>> fib(7)
13
>>> fib(8)
21
>>> fib(9)
34
...
>>> fib(30)
832040
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code was that the loop did not create the item indexed 1, so after the loop you were able to change this item because it did not exist.
I would suggest "hardcode" 0 and 1 at the beginning, then using a recursion to define fibonacci function

```
def fib(n):
    if 0<=n<2: return n
    else: return fib(n-2)+fib(n-1)
```

and then just call

```
fib(i)
```

to get i-th item or make a list of all x fibonacci values using a list comprehension

```
[fib(i) for i in range(x)]
```